# React component not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux, render

I have a react component that grabs image urls from a service. I take these urls and just create some `<img .../>` elements to show the images.

There is 1 image list per row. This works on the initial load, but when I start removing rows (done by splicing the element out of the global state's array, handled by redux), the row is deleted correctly, but the images don't change. It seems that each row's images will "leak" over.

Here's a screencap:

[image: screencap]

I'm thinking I need to force a re-render somewhere, maybe at the parent level?

Here's my container code:

```
class SourceMediaPreviewContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      source: {},
      media: [],
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    const { source: _source } = this.props;
    const { data } = (await this.getMedia({ source: _source })) || {};
    const { media = [], ...source } = data || {};
    this.setState({ source, media });
  }
  async getMedia({ source }) {
    return describeSourceMedia({ source });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="asb-source-media-preview">
        {this.state.media.map((media, i) => (
          <img
            key={media.url}
            className="asb-source-media-preview__img"
            src={media.media_url}
            alt={media.title}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  // mediaSource: state.asb.mediaSource,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>
  bindActionCreators(
    {
      // ...mediaSourceOperations,
    },
    dispatch,
  );

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(SourceMediaPreviewContainer);
```

Comment: what is the `mediaSource` prop passed from the state? It looks like you never use it inside your component

Comment: What does delete row function like? And, try key={media.media_url}.

Comment: @quirimmo: This is unused and requires cleanup.

Comment: and how do you notify to the component that the image has been removed? React renders again only if props or internal state changed

Comment: @quirimmo: when the item is sliced out of the array, redux informs react that the state has changed and requires a render. You can see this working correctly as the words associated with the removed row disappears, what's weird is that the images don't render correctly

Comment: there is something weird going on there, do you mind to create a fiddle/stackblitz to check it?

Comment: I found the issue. The parent container which uses this container needed to have the correct `key={...}` identifiers, using the index `i` was not enough in this container but in the parent container as well.

Comment: @PGT index is never a good choice for key value to begin with. Official document always advices to use unique identifier instead: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys